# Как запустить Qemu для эмулятора MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan?

Tags: qml, эмулятор, qt

У меня установлены все необхоидмые компоненты для разработки в Qt, QtQuick для разных платформ, в том числе и для MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan:

[image]

Вот окно настроек эмулятора:

[image]

Когда я нажимаю Test, выходит окно с ошибкой:

```
Could not connect to host: Connection refused
Did you start Qemu?
```

Когда компилирую простой сгенерированный код при создании QML application:

```
:-1: error: Cannot deploy: Qemu was not running. It has now been started up for you, but it will take a bit of time until it is ready. Please try again then.
```

Как мне запустить этот Qemu ? Я его установил под kubuntu... нужно настроить как-то?

Answer (score 1):

Hartman Emulator как раз не установлен. По всей видимости, нужно выбрать соответствующую позицию во вкладке Experimental - Hartman - Hartman Emulator.